# Prevent Div from filling parent Div width after it wraps

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a div within its parent div like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="yourdiv">
        <div id='one'>1</div>
        <div id='two'>2</div>
        <div id='one'>1</div>
        <div id='two'>2</div>
        <div id='one'>1</div>
        <div id='two'>2</div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
#yourdiv {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#yourdiv > div
{
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
}
#two {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

This works fine when the child div does not 'wrap' as you can see below.

[image]

However, once there are too many child elements to fit the page width, the elements wrap to a second row and 'yourdiv' fills its parent width like so:

[image]

The child elements are no longer centered on the page because 'yourdiv' now fills its parents width. How can I fix it so that 'yourdiv' shrinks its width to its content so that the child elements are centred no matter how many there are?

EDIT:
The desired result is:
[image]

Comment: /*for visualization purposes*/ made my eyes bleed :D

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using flexbox.

To center your elements horizontally use

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

on the container.

Play around with `flex-grow`, `min-width` and `max-width` on the children to tune your layout.

Comment: In addition to the answer, I would add the following reference where I think well explain the operation of the flexbox. [Link to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Turn your css to flex and it's too much easier. Your just have to set `#yourdiv` `flex-wrap: wrap;` to make it wrap when overflow and `justify-content: center;` to center child element:

```css
  #wrapper {
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #yourdiv {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  #yourdiv>div {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
  }

  #one {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  #two {
    background-color: brown;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="yourdiv">
    <div id='one'>1</div>
    <div id='two'>2</div>
    <div id='one'>1</div>
    <div id='two'>2</div>
    <div id='one'>1</div>
    <div id='two'>2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When there are an odd number of items this does not work as it centres the items on the bottom row rather than left justify them. If I set justify-content: left, I lose the centering. Thoughts?

Comment: @SteveW it will be on the left if you set `justify-content: flex-start`, I don't understand what you are trying to approach here, can you please post an image describe it?

Comment: The image you posted is perfect for 6 elements. If you remove the 6th element it should appear exactly as before but without the final brown '2'. However, the remaining '2' and '1' on the bottom row move to the horizontal center of the div. If I could fix that it will be great.

Comment: I added an example for the desired output in my question.

Comment: I have tried several ways with flex but it doesn't work. I think you have to set some @media query to responsive (in case you know exacly width of each items)

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for those cases, you should read those good articles:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

and play this game to understand Flexbox while playing a game:

- https://flexboxfroggy.com/

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#yourdiv {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#yourdiv > div {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.one {
  background-color: blue;
}

.two {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">    
  <div id="yourdiv">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```